# Trying to get Gloss Graphics library working

Tags: haskell, graphics

I'm trying to find a simple graphics library for haskell and Gloss seemed simple, from the examples.

I've taken a very simple example, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
import Graphics.Gloss
displayInWindow "My Window" (200, 200) (10, 10) blue (circle 80)
```

Compiling with `ghc test.hs` I get:

```
 compilation IS NOT required
 Undefined symbols:
 "_glosszm1zi3zi4zi1_GraphicsziGlossziDataziColor_blue_closure", referenced from:
  _Main_main_info in test.o
  _Main_main_srt in test.o
 "_glosszm1zi3zi4zi1_GraphicsziGlossziDataziPicture_circle_closure", referenced from:
  _spy_info in test.o
  _spy_srt in test.o
 "___stginit_glosszm1zi3zi4zi1_GraphicsziGloss_", referenced from:
  ___stginit_Main_ in test.o                 
 "_glosszm1zi3zi4zi1_GraphicsziGlossziInternalsziInterfaceziDisplay_displayInWindow_closure",      referenced from:
  _Main_main_info in test.o
  _Main_main_srt in test.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have *slightly* more success with ghci. Running the same code, I get a white rectangle to appear, but it doesn't draw anything and is unresponsive. I have to quit the process to get back control of my terminal.

I'd also be interested in alternative graphics libraries if something else is more suitable. I'm finding it a bit difficult to know what libraries are worth looking at. My requirements are vague, I just want to draw something to the screen.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: You can also just play with http://dac4.designacourse.com:8000/game instead :)

Comment: @MatrixFrog: That used to be excellent, but what happened to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just need to use `ghc --make test.hs` instead. Newer versions of `ghc` make `--make` the default.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem before.  Glad you fond the solution too.